# OpenVPN: cannot open domain webpages in browser

Tags: openvpn, mac-osx

strange problem here!

I am using VPN to connect to my work network (openvpn, hosted by my institution, I'm managing it, so I can make changes).
Everything works fine, meaning that all traffic is routed through the VPN as it should (at least it seems so), I have internet access, I can access restricted services (e.g. git, shared folders) that require me to be on the same network etc.

The problem is that with browsers (tried Safari, Firefox and Chrome), I cannot access webpages that are hosted within the institution's local network.
All other web pages work fine (I am posting this connected to the VPN).

Let's assume our domain is `domain.com`
Anything hosted under `domain.com` cannot be accessed via browser.
e.g. `webserver1.domain.com` won't open in browser. Safari states:

```
Safari can't connect to the server
Safari can't open the page domain.com because Safari can't connect to server domain.com
```

In terminal `webserver1.domain.com` is resolved without issues (`nslookup`), I can ping it, and `traceroute` seems ok.

If I try to checkout a git repo under `webserver1.domain.com` (from terminal), it works fine.
If I try to mount a shared folder (using Finder and the url), also ok

All other services work fine (I can mount shared drives, send/receive mails, even use printers). As far as I can tell, everything but browser access works fine.
The same VPN configurations work fine in iOS (iOS safari can open `domain.com` pages when connected to the VPN just fine)

I'm on MacOS 12.0.1 and using Tunnelblick 3.8.7a to connect to VPN.

I can also access some webpages using IP address and not url (getting the security warning as ssl does not work).
As mentioned, DNS is ok and resolves everything.

My *server.conf* is below:

```
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/xxxxxxx.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/xxxxxxx.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
topology subnet

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "comp-lzo no"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you have a proxy set up perchance?

Comment: No, no proxies are used.

Comment: Maybe you hit an outgoing firewall from your institution? If a git checkout works perfectly, the vpn tunnel is not the issue here.

Comment: What is this "server.conf" you're showing us?   And what is the meaning of "server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0" and "route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0"?

Comment: Hi, "server.conf" is the configuration file for the OpenVPN server.
I'm not 100% sure what these settings do (found them in the guide I followed).
I believe the first one is the vpn network configuration and the 2nd one is about routing?

Answer (score 0):

...and today suddenly, and without changing anything, everything works!

Don't know what to say... I haven't restarted my computer nor the VPN server...

Strange things!